# Shuffling ArrayList in multiple threads

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an static ArrayList.Each thread runs  to shuffle the ArrayList,then I got the wrong result.

```
public void collectoinTest() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                    Collections.shuffle(list);
                    System.out.println( list);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The output look like this somtime:

```
[8, 9, 6, 5, 1, 7, 3, 4, 6, 0]
```

It has duplicate elements,anyone can explain this?

Comment: This is whats known as race condition. I suggest reading up on multithreading.

Comment: wrap the line: `Collections.shuffle(list);` with: `synchronized (YourClassName.class) {
                            Collections.shuffle(list);
                        }` and try again. Needless to say that `YourClassName` should be substitute with the *real* name of your class

Comment: Why are you shuffling a list of size 10 with 100 threads?? For performance gain??  Seems a bad distribution of work because lists are mutable and two threads can swap two different elements with the same element( race condition) , thats why you are scratching your head

Comment: How can you expect this to work correctly when you have 100 thread simultaneously shuffling the the SAME list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that shuffle works internally is it swaps list elements:

```
T tmp = list.get(from);
list.set(from, list.get(to));
list.set(to, tmp);
```

If you've got multiple threads, the actions of the threads might interleave, e.g.:

```
T tmp1 = list.get(from1);
                                  T tmp2 = list.get(from2);
                                  list.set(from2, list.get(to2));
list.set(from1, list.get(to1));
                                  list.set(to2, tmp2);
list.set(to1, tmp1);
```

or

```
T tmp1 = list.get(from1);
                                  T tmp2 = list.get(from2);
list.set(from1, list.get(to1));
list.set(to1, tmp1);
                                  list.set(from2, list.get(to2));
                                  list.set(to2, tmp2);
```

But the ordering of the interleaving is non-deterministic: it depends on many things that are hard to anticipate. This is especially true as there are 100 threads working on the same list.

Some of the potential interleavings may cause incorrect values to be written, because the value of `from` is no longer the value that you previously wrote.

Consider the very simple example of a list `[0, 1]`, and two threads which are trying to swap the elements (so `from1 = from2 = 0; to1 = to2 = 1;`). If they interleave like this (just as one example; other interleavings may have the same effect):

```
                                  T tmp2 = list.get(0);
T tmp1 = list.get(0);
                                  list.set(0, list.get(1));
                                  list.set(1, tmp2);
list.set(0, list.get(1));
list.set(1, tmp1);
```

Then the final list will be `[0, 0]`. [<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/IguXga)

There are two ways to avoid this:

- The easiest is not to do it in multiple threads; then there can't be interference between a thread and itself.
- Make the threads only operate on a portion of the list (e.g. use `list.subList` to extract a view of a portion of the list). Then the threads won't interfere, because they're operating on separate parts of the data. However, then the shuffling will be limited to just swapping within those sublists; elements can't move as far within the list as if you shuffle the entire list in one go.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple threads which update your list. Since you aren't using any synchronization, there is possible that you will have an inconsistent state for the list because of the changes made by those threads. It's possible for two threads to update the same element position with two different values and you end up with duplicated value.

You should synchronize over your collection like this:

```
   synchronized (list) {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        System.out.println(list);
   }
```

The code above works as long as you don't update the list from outside the `run` method. If you do that, it may be required to declare the list as a field or static member and then use the appropriate lock.